# symfony: trying to run all the tests of an app

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, functional-testing

I'm trying to launch all the functional tests of an app, but when I do it, I get this:

```
[mbpPlatformApi] functionaldistritoActionsTest.......................dubious
    Test returned status 255
    Failed tests: 0
[mbpPlatformApi] functionaleventoActionsTest..........................dubious
    Test returned status 255
    Failed tests: 0

Failed Test                     Stat  Total   Fail  Errors  List of Failed
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 functionaldistritoActionsTest    255      1      1      0  0
pi] functionaleventoActionsTest   255      1      1      0  0
pi] 
Failed 10/10 test scripts, 0.00% okay. 10/0 subtests failed, 0.00% okay.
```

No problem if I run the tests separatelly.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered this problem before and it was due to running out of memory when running the test suite but having enough if run individually.

try adding this line to the top of

/test/bootstrap/lib/functional.php

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get a status of 'dubious' it means that the test(s) died before it could complete. This is usually caused by:

- errors in the test code
- lacking required libraries
- libraries / dependencies crashing

If you run the test-file by itself it will give you some feedback on whats happening.